# Combining likes from url.com and www.url.com

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

At a website of ours, we've had a normal FB like button and gathered some likes. After a while we realised we would like to be able to post to people liking our site. I created an app and added the fb:app_id meta tag and the app started gathering the likes rightaway. However, the likes we had from before are not counted in the app although they are still shown in the number by our like button.

Have a look at https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://leveransrapport.se compared to https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.leveransrapport.se. The first one shows 105 shares whereas the second one shows 10 likes.

What am I missing?

My intention is to get all the likes to show up in the app page for the admins.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue goes beyond Facebook. This is known as the canonical problem and causes search engines to treat the URLs as different and split search ranking!

Ideally you want all URLs to map to one of the two (www. or non-www.) to prevent this kind of problem.

You could put something like this in your .htaccess file (google shows you more examples)

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Thanks for helping out, but I'm not sure I agree to this being unrelated to Facebook. We 301-redirect people going to leveransrapport.se to www.leveransrapport.se, which the URL Lint tool provided by Facebook correctly reports, but still the discrepancy between number of likes is there.

Comment: Seeing this now. Could it be historically? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307507/different-like-counts-on-url-com-and-www-url-com

I checked my domain and it has the same like counts for no-www and www

Check this: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bobbelderbos.com 

original: http://www.bobbelderbos.com/
301: http://bobbelderbos.com/
Final URL is in bold (this is the URL we tried to extract metadata from) => this is the 2nd one

This is the .htaccess at work, even better would be to set og:url explicitly

Answer (score -1):

Many browsers appends http to url without protocol so that url.com will become http://url.com and www.url.com will become http://www.url.com. It depends on how the app treats urls. Since I have not programmed with FB API I cannot add much than general information

**Edit:**

According to [this link](http://webhostinghelpguy.inmotionhosting.com/homepage/www-vs-no-www-on-a-canonical-url/) and some on internet the two makes no difference and it is a matter of preference> I think you have to check if the links is not supposed to be https not http!