# Different like counts on url.com and www.url.com

Tags: button, facebook-like

I [asked this question earlier](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8531330/combining-likes-from-url-com-and-www-url-com) on StackOverflow, but did not realise there was a facebook.stackoverflow.com.

We're experiencing different like counts on our website whether we check www.url.com or just url.com. I'm afraid this question might be similar to [this question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8340883/different-counters-for-likes-in-the-site-and-likes-in-the-facebook-page) since we had a normal Like button on our site first, and then decided to create an app for it in order to follow up and post updates to our fans. Is this a matter of "No, likes can't be merged" or have we missed something? Our goal is to have all the likes available to us in the admin page.

Have a look at: https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.leveransrapport.se
Compared to: https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://leveransrapport.se

On a side note, people who did Like us before we added the app, can Like the site again and we'll get duplicate likes from that person. This surely must point to some error somewhere?

Comment: Just a stab, but is there an id and URL you can set?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the non-www link you have above is counts from **before** you changed to using a 301 redirect.  Or **before** you correctly specified the og:url to be the www one.  So if one page had og:url of non-www, and the other one with, then facebook is going to treat it as two separate IDs.  However, it looks like all activity is going to the www one, so I don't think going forward you're going to have any troubles.